# Error in form validation using Javascript in email field

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "form.css" />
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <h2><center>SignUp</center></h2>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label><b>Email</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>User Name</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="userid" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Re-enter Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="pwd1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Enter DOB</b></label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" required>
    </div>
    
      <input type="reset" class="cancelbtn" value="Reset">
      <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" value="Submit">
    
    </div>   
    

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried beginner level javascript validation to ensure that email field cannot be left blank.However on running the code, no validation is being performed for the email field. That is, no popup appears and directly the required attribute of userid gets displayed. Can anyone point out the errors in the code?

Comment: Might help to have a fiddle, but did you `console.log(x)`? If so, what's the value?

Comment: you have missed required keyword!!

Comment: you need custom validation, you should remove "required" keyword from all the input element of your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard HTML5 validation is always performed before the form gets submitted. That means that if that validation fails, i.e. any of your required fields don't have a valid value, the `submit` event is never even triggered and your custom validation doesn't run at all.

This makes sense, because why would your custom validation need to run if the form isn't ready to be submitted to begin with?

In other words, **there are no errors in your code, it behaves as expected**.
If you always want your custom validation to run, you need to remove the `required` attributes on all the other fields so that there's no standard validation and instead validate those fields in your custom validation.

Answer (score 0):

In the `email` input box, you don't have `required` condition mentioned, hence form will get submitted if you try to submit without entering any values.

If you don't want this, you need to add `required`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "form.css" />
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <h2><center>SignUp</center></h2>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label><b>Email</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>User Name</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="userid" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Re-enter Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="pwd1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Enter DOB</b></label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" required>
    </div>
    
      <input type="reset" class="cancelbtn" value="Reset">
      <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" value="Submit">
    
    </div>   
    

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added the **HTML5** validation on each field except the email field.

Look at here:

```
placeholder="Enter User Name" name="userid" required>
                                            ^^^ this require attribute
```

So first your **HTML5** validation will execute and after that your **javascript** will work.

`required` attribute is validation in **HTML5** and most of browser support that.

To check your javascript, first fill the form except the email field and after that the alert will work.

Comment: There is a custom validation for email

Comment: @brk I know that is in javascript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should include you JS code at the end of the `<body>` section, not in the `<head>`.

Second, you should use jQuery to perform that just including the CDN resource link at the end of the body. You can see here that is really simple:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
    Email
    <input type="text" id="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();

    if(email == '') 
      alert('Fill the email');
    else
      this.submit();
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or just adjust yours:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "form.css">

</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <h2><center>SignUp</center></h2>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label><b>Email</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email">
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>User Name</b></label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter User Name" name="userid" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Re-enter Password</b></label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" name="pwd1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><b>Enter DOB</b></label>
       <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" required>
    </div>

      <input type="reset" class="cancelbtn" value="Reset">
      <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" value="Submit">

    </div>   
  <script>
  function validateForm() {
      document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      var x = document.getElementById('email').value;
      if (x == "") {
          alert("Name must be filled out");
          return false;
      }
  }
  </script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck!